# Where is perl dbi getting its error string from and can it be modified to provide more useful info?

Tags: perl, dbi

I am working on a project where I am reading in log files and process them and load them into a Postgres database. These log files are seperated by month, meaning I give my script a particular month and it goes through the directories (actually they are directories for each server and there are 8 servers) and grabs the file and uploads them. This code is what loads them into the database:

```
sub insert_n_gridftp_usage {
eval {
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT into $stats_table VALUES ($epoch, '$servername', $currentnumhash{'RETR'}, $currentbyteshash{'RETR'}, $currentnumhash{'STOR'}, $currentbyteshash{'STOR'}, $currentnumhash{'ERET'}, $currentbyteshash{'ERET'}, $currentnumhash{'ESTO'}, $currentbyteshash{'ESTO'}, $currentnumhash{'LIST'}, $currentbyteshash{'LIST'}, $currentnumhash{'NLST'}, $currentbyteshash{'NLST'}, $currentnumhash{'MLSD'}, $currentbyteshash{'MLSD'}, $currentnum, $currentbytes);") || die; 
    $sth->execute;
    $dbh->commit;
} or
do {
    $stats_fails++;
    eval { $dbh->rollback };
}
```

}

The table has a unique index constraint that prevents duplicate records being loaded. Now when this statement encounters a duplicate I get this error on stderr:

```
DBD::Pg::st execute failed: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "transfer_unique"DETAIL:  Key (starttime, endtime, file)=(1366822840, 1366822840, /dev/null) already exists. at ./database_load_script.pl line 196, <LOGFILE> line 1332302.
```

The LOGFILE is my variable the number after the word line is my variable $linenum. I did not set this error string anywhere in my code. So, where is this string coming from? Is it possible to modify this string to point out the file its reading from as well? (I have a variable for the filename). Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can indeed modify what's output when your query fails. Currently you're doing:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("...") || die;
```

Which means that `die` is taking its default argument, the value of `$!`. You can, however, also pass a custom string to `die`, and it will instead output that on standard error; that string, if double-quoted, can interpolate variables just like any other. The other thing to know about `die` arguments is that they are magical, in that the absence of a trailing newline will cause `die` to append information on the position of the error, both in your code, and in any files from which you happen to be reading at the time; if you include a trailing newline in your `die` argument, this will not occur.

So, assuming your filename is contained in a variable `$filename`, you might do this:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('...') || die "$! at $filename line $linenum\n";
```

Which would result in an error resembling:

```
DBD::Pg::st_execute failed: ERROR: [...] at /path/to/logfile line 12345
```

Comment: Just to add to Aaron's answer, you can also tinker with the errors DBI throws with RaiseError if you set DBI's HandleError attribute. See http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.628/DBI.pm#HandleError and HandleSetErr.